# Find a representation of the vector by giving appropriate values for the points A and B such that neither A nor B is the origin?

Tags: vectors

Find a representation of the vector $AB =\langle0,3,8\rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by giving appropriate values for the points $A$ and $B$ such that neither $A$ nor $B$ is the origin.

Could someone please explain how I go about this? I am really not sure I understand how to approach this.

Comment: Do you mean adding a constant vector to each point??

Comment: i thin so? my thought is i take a point like A = (1,1,1) and add the vector to get B = (1, 4, 9) but i just wanna make sure i understand it right.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take (almost) any point $A$ different from the origin, say $A=(1,0,0)$, and translate it by the given vector to obtain the coordinates of $B$.

> Simply add the coordinates: $B=(1,3,8)$ in my example.